# What's the update area of UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect function?

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to update a rectangle area of a layered window using UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect function, but I get confused when I read the doc.

According to the doc of [UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633557(v%3Dvs.85)),

> UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect always updates the entire window. To update part of a window, use the traditional WM_PAINT and set the blend value using SetLayeredWindowAttributes.

However the second parameter `pULWInfo` contains a member `prcDirty` which seems to be used to update a certain area instead of the whole window,

> The area to be updated. This parameter can be NULL. If it is non-NULL, only the area in this rectangle is updated from the source DC.

These two descriptions seem contradictory to me. Are they referring to different steps of updating a layered window? What is the mechanism behind this function? And What's the difference if I try to update asynchronously by handling WM_PAINT instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a documentation bug.   It looks like the documentation for [`UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633557(v%3Dvs.85)) copied most of the info from [`UpdateLayeredWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow); however, `UpdateLayeredWindow` doesn't have a dirty rectangle parameter.   Therefore, the comment would be correct for `UpdateLayeredWindow` but incorrect for `UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect`.